# Java как поймать сигнал (или событие) о завершении windows?

Tags: java, windows

У меня есть приложения на Java. Я знаю, что когда **Windows** выключается, он отправляет сообщение **WM_QUERYENDSESSION** каждому приложению. Это позволяет легко обнаружить, когда **Windows** выключается.

Как мне на Java поймать этот сигнал? Возможно мне и вовсе надо отлавливать событие, вместо сигнала. Подскажите как быть? Или в каком направление мне надо искать, чтобы решать такую задачу?